# Codeigniter Uninitialized string offset- Loop Array Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting an error once I loop an array then passing it to the model.

**Controller:**

```
if (isset($dataRow)) {
  foreach($dataRow as $key => $dataVal) :
    foreach($dataVal as $key => $dataSume)
      $fArray = $dataSume;
      $y =  count ($dataSume);
      for($x=0; $x < 1; $x++ ) {
            $this->varOrder->addCount($fArray[0], $fArray[1], $fArray[2], $fArray[3], $fArray[4], $fArray[5], $fArray[6], $fArray[7], $fArray[8], $flag2);

      }
  endforeach;
```

**Model:**

```
function addCount($ref_no, $sku, $desc, $qty, $uom, $loc, $batch, $expiry, $remarks, $flag2) {
  $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO SCH_CYCLECOUNT (
    REF_NO, SKU, DESCRIPTION, QTY, UOM, LOCATION, BATCH, EXPIRY_DATE, REMARKS, PROG_ID, 
        COUNT_TYPE, FLAG1, FLAG3, STATUS )
    VALUES
    ('" . $ref_no . "', '" . $sku . "', '" . $desc . "', '" . $qty . "', '" . $uom . "', '" . 
        $loc . "', '" . $batch . "', '" . $expiry . "', '" . $remarks . "', '" . $flag2 . "', 
        'Stock on Hand', '1', '1' ,'WAITING FOR COUNT')");
  return true;
}
```

**Array- value of $dataRow:** This is why I looped twice.

```
array(12) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [11]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } }
```

its my error is in my looping? thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you share `print_r($dataRow);` output?

Comment: $datarow in Array, that come on the excel file that I uploaded. the wierd thing is when i upload the file with 12 row lines then its successfully insert, but once I the line from 13 and up then that the time offset error occured. array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> float(22) } }